# Adding text in prompt()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Window that I want to automate:
[image: Window that I want to automate]

PROBLEM: Our team decided to create an authentication for our staging environment. My tests now have to do an extra step filling these out. I found out that 'prompt()' cannot be captured by typical weblocators.

I found some answers google but it was only for alert(), how can I input my username and password so that my test can proceed.

Comment: That's not `prompt()`. That's the browser responding to an HTTP "Authentication Required" response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an authentication request, not a `prompt()` box. You can supply credentials in the URL: `https://username:password@hostname/path`